# window.open alternatives to run php file

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript where it gets the dom values and creates a link which points to a PHP file as below:

```
function extractValue() {
        var jobName = document.getElementById('table_jobName').innerText;
        var error = document.getElementById('table_error').innerText;
        var bugId = document.getElementById('table_bugId').innerText;
        var status = document.getElementById('table_status').value;
        var comments = document.getElementById('table_comments').innerText;
        window.open("http://localhost:8000/save_infra.php?jobName=" + jobName + "&error=" + error +
           "&bugId=" + bugId + "&status=" + status + "&comments=" + comments);
      }
```

I don't actually want a new window to open and do the php task. I just need to pass on the value to php. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use an asynchronous GET request (AJAX). this will not open a new window and your Http request will be sent.

```
xhttp.open("GET", Your calculated URL , true);
xhttp.send();
```

If you are using JQuery, there are functions in it to easily send http requests and handle the response, have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: i created a xhttp object in javascript nad I am trying to do this:
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "save_infra.php?jobName=" + jobName + "&error=" + error +
          "&bugId=" + bugId + "&status=" + status + "&comments=" + comments, true);
        xhttp.send();
Its not doing that php stuffs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ajax feature to do the same. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
This is will allow you to send the data Asynchronously